# Deducing variadic member type from types of arguments passed to constructor

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm trying to deduce the type of a member variable from the types of arguments passed to its class' constructor. The constructor of the class (a PublishSubscribe class) receives two parameters, each representing variadic types (one variadic pack for sending, one for receiving).

The code I'm trying to get working is the following:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Types>
struct TopicTypes {};

TopicTypes<int> type_subscribe_topics;
TopicTypes<int,double> type_publish_topics;

template <typename... TReceives>
class PublishSubscribe
{
  public:
    template <  typename... TReceives,  template <typename...> class TR,
                typename... TSends,     template <typename...> class TS>
    PublishSubscribe(const TR<TReceives...>&,
                     const TS<TSends...>&){}

    private:
    std::tuple<TReceives...> member_; 
};

class UserClass : public PublishSubscribe{
    public:
     UserClass()
        : PublishSubscribe(
                type_subscribe_topics,
                type_publish_topics
        ){}
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
variadic3.cpp:13:17: error: declaration of 'class ... TReceives'
     template <  typename... TReceives,  template <typename...> class TR,
                 ^
variadic3.cpp:9:11: error:  shadows template parm 'class ... TReceives'
 template <typename ... TReceives>
```

How would one template the PublishSubscribe class with the types of type_subscribe_topics? I would require `PublishSubscribe<magic(decltype(type_subscribe_topics))>` which would default to `PublishSubscribe<int>` in this particular case..

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the same template name in a class template and member function template.  You have

```
template <typename... TReceives>
class PublishSubscribe
```

and

```
template <  typename... TReceives,  template <typename...> class TR,
            typename... TSends,     template <typename...> class TS>
PublishSubscribe(const TR<TReceives...>&,
                 const TS<TSends...>&){}
```

Which both use `TReceives`.  You either need to change the name in one of the templates or, if you are using the `TReceives` that you passed to the class you can just get rid of it from the function which would look like

```
template <                          template <typename...> class TR,
            typename... TSends,     template <typename...> class TS>
PublishSubscribe(const TR<TReceives...>&,
                 const TS<TSends...>&){}
```

---

You are not going to be able to use the template parameters of the constructor to define the types the the `member_` tuple should use.  You could make the class less general and just take a tuple like

```
template <typename T> 
class PublishSubscribe
```

and then you would use it like

```
PublishSubscribe<decltype(some_tuple)> foo(some_tuple, some_other_tuple);
```

and `member_` would just become `T member_;`

Comment: Right! I'm using the same type because I want the member_ variable to have the same type as the type of the parameter passed to the constructor.

Comment: @MihaiGalos Oh, I'm not sure you can do that.  AFAIK member variables cannot depend on a member function template parameter as that is not known when the class is compiled.

Comment: Humm. I see. What can be done here to create a "generic" template for templating both type_subscribe_topics *and* PublishSubscribe?

Comment: @MihaiGalos Instead of being completly generic are you willing to just accept a tuple as the template type?  If so you could just have `template <typename... TReceives> class PublishSubscribe` and then you would use it like `PublishSubscribe<decltype(some_tuple)> foo(some_tuple, some_other_tuple);` and `member_` wouyld just become `T member_;`

Comment: unfortunately not. I need to develop this PublishSubscribe class with this templating. If not possible, I need to specialize the class when inheriting from it : 
`class UserClass : public PublishSubscribe<int>`.

Comment: Please edit your answer by adding the "you cannot" part you mentioned. I will then approve it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @MihaiGalos Edited.  Let me know if that covers it.